# Web Firestore behavior on multiple subscriptions for the same document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

If I am calling `onSnapshot` on document X (let's say Locations/x) multiple times within the same application,
does the Firestore web client optimize this by combining the subscription?

ie:

1. Will I be charged for one or multiple reads per document update?
2. Will my client be receiving multiple network calls or just one per document update?

I am using web Firebase v9.16.0

Comment: Aside from my answer, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-drastically-reduce-the-number-of-reads-when-no-documents-are-changed-in-firestore-8760e2f25e9e) will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I am calling onSnapshot on document X (let's say Locations/x) multiple times within the same application, does the Firestore web client optimize this by combining the subscription?

The offline persistence for the web is disabled by default. So if you want to have a local copy of your database, then you have to enable it, by calling the `enablePersistence` method. This means that when you attach a listener, you'll have to pay a read for each document the query returns. All subsequent calls will be read from the cache, but only as long as nothing is changed on the Firebase servers. So if you read a single document, then you'll have to pay for a single read. All the other reads will be from the cache. All reads that are coming from the cache don't have a cost. But remember, according to the [official documentation regarding pricing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#listens):

> If offline persistence is enabled and the listener is disconnected for more than 30 minutes (for example, if the user goes offline), you will be charged for reads as if you had issued a brand-new query.

So if you go offline for more than 30 minutes, when the listener is reattached, you have to pay for a new read.

> 1. Will I be charged for one or multiple reads per document update?

The update operation is not related in any way to a read operation. So when you update a document there is no read operation that should be paid.

> 2. Will my client be receiving multiple network calls or just one per document update?

Once the listener is attached, you'll get a single connection per update. Nothing else will be triggered.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. As you mentioned `enablePersistence` is required to persist between sessions (tab close then open). So does that mean without `enablePersistence` if I have multiple onSnapshot of a same document at the same time within the same app, will I be charged multiple reads for every document update?

Comment: Yes, if offline persistence is disabled, meaning you don't use `enablePersistence`, you will be charged for reads as if you had issued a brand-new query whenever the listener disconnects and reconnects.

Comment: Hm... let me rephrase.
I am not asking about onSnapshot disconnecting and reconnecting, but rather first onSnapshot on a document A, and remains connected, while another onSnapshot is called on the same document A (within the same application).
Would that be considered two connections or one? and in that case does offline persistence even matter? since cache can come from inMemory (instead of localStorage).

Comment: It will be considered only one. Office persistence helps us to have an offline copy of the database that can be accessed while the device losses connection. But the cache is stored on local storage, not in the memory.